# CSV to JSON array only numbers

Tags: python, json, csv

```
import csv
import json

myDict = {}
jsonStr = json.dumps(myDict)
print(jsonStr)
with open('test - Cópia.csv', 'rb',encoding=) as csvdata:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvdata,fieldnames=['Time', 'Yaw','Pitch','Roll','Ax','Ay','Az','Gx','Gy','Gz','Mx','My','Mz'])
    json.dump([row for row in reader], open('output.json', 'w+'))
```

I have a problem that I can´t figure it out yet. I Have a csv only with numbers, no header. With 14 columns, Each column name are above in `[]`. I have to create a JSON that puts the key name and each key name have an array with all the numbers that I have in csv.

CSV is like this :

```
1364.00,0.15,0.36,-0.13,-3.24,-0.42,-0.15,0.90,0.00,-0.01,0.02,0.26,0.01,-0.04
1374.00,0.30,0.76,-0.25,-3.25,-0.41,-0.13,0.91,0.00,-0.00,0.02,0.26,0.01,-0.04
1384.00,0.45,1.08,-0.35,-3.17,-0.41,-0.10,1.00,-0.00,-0.01,0.02,0.26,0.01,-0.07
1394.00,0.61,1.44,-0.49,-3.21,-0.40,-0.10,1.01,-0.00,-0.01,0.02,0.26,0.01,-0.07
1404.00,0.77,1.81,-0.65,-3.25,-0.40,-0.11,1.00,-0.01,-0.01,0.02,0.26,0.01,-0.07
1414.00,0.92,2.12,-0.83,-3.29,-0.38,-0.14,0.98,-0.00,-0.01,0.02,0.26,0.01,-0.07
1424.00,1.05,2.43,-1.01,-3.34,-0.37,-0.14,0.96,-0.00,-0.01,0.02,0.26,0.01,-0.07
1434.00,1.21,2.78,-1.15,-2.95,-0.38,-0.10,0.91,-0.00,-0.01,0.02,0.26,0.01,-0.05
1444.00,1.35,3.10,-1.27,-2.97,-0.37,-0.09,0.90,-0.00,-0.01,0.02,0.26,0.01,-0.05
1454.00,1.49,3.42,-1.39,-2.99,-0.37,-0.10,0.90,-0.00,-0.01,0.02,0.26,0.01,-0.05
1464.00,1.62,3.74,-1.57,-3.02,-0.37,-0.14,0.90,-0.00,-0.01,0.02,0.26,0.01,-0.05
1474.00,1.74,4.08,-1.77,-3.05,-0.38,-0.16,0.87,-0.00,-0.01,0.02,0.26,0.01,-0.05
2054.00,8.39,14.06,-10.55,-0.08,-0.05,0.06,1.20,-0.01,0.02,-0.00,0.24,-0.01,-0.04
```

and I want to create a JSON file like this

```
session 1 { "Time": [an array with all the numbers that are in column 0 of csv],
            "Pitch": [an array with all the numbers that are in column 1 of csv],
            ...
}
```

Comment: What have you done to even *attempt* to produce this output?

Comment: Hint: You will need to read the entire CSV file and gather the data for the two arrays _before_ creating the JSON file.

Comment: @martineau thanks. will search about that

Comment: Recommend you take a look at `pandas.read_csv` and the json output types.

Comment: Each row of your CSV file contains 14 values, but you only define 13 fieldnames. Please correct this discrepancy — or describe what you want to do with these extra values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to do it using only built-in functions and modules included in Python's standard library.

As I mentioned in a comment, you will need to read in the entire CSV file first. This is because its row and columns need to be [*transposed*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose) in order to output them as an array the way you want. Fortunately doing that is easy using the built-in [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function.

Also note the use of [`csv.reader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) instead of a [`csv.DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader). This change was made because the `zip()` function couldn't (easily) be used on a list of dictionaries. The field names *are* still used, but it's not until the dictionary is created as describe next. **Note** that this will ignore the extra value in each row that does not have a fieldname.

You can use a [dictionary comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#dictionary-displays) to create one formatted the way you want before calling `json.dump()` to write it to the output file.

```
import csv
import json


fieldnames = 'Time','Yaw','Pitch','Roll','Ax','Ay','Az','Gx','Gy','Gz','Mx','My','Mz'
csv_filepath = 'test - Cópia.csv'
json_filepath = 'output.json'

with open(csv_filepath, 'r', newline='') as csv_file:
    rows = (map(float, row) for row in csv.reader(csv_file))  # Expr to read entire CSV file.
    data = tuple(zip(*rows))  # Transpose the CSV file's rows and cols.

my_dict = {'session 1': {fieldname: row for fieldname in fieldnames for row in data}}

with open(json_filepath, 'w') as json_file:
    json.dump(my_dict, json_file, indent=4)

print('done')
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using Pandas to take care of the details of reading CSVs. It also has convenient features for manipulating the data.

```
import pandas as pd
import json

# Note that your column names include one less column than the sample CSV
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', names=['Time', 'Yaw', 'Pitch', 'Roll', 'Ax', 'Ay', 'Az', 'Gx', 'Gy', 'Gz', 'Mx', 'My', 'Mz', 'extra'])

# Note that this can be simplified if you don't need the top-level "session 1"
output = {'session 1': df.to_dict(orient='list')}

with open('output.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(output, f)
```

If for some reason you need a solution using only stdlib, here's one which uses a `defaultdict` to build the inner output. An important note is that the csv module reads things as strings by default, so you need to convert the numbers to floats otherwise they will be quoted in the output json.

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

inner_output = defaultdict(list)

fieldnames = ['Time', 'Yaw', 'Pitch', 'Roll', 'Ax', 'Ay', 'Az', 'Gx', 'Gy', 'Gz', 'Mx', 'My', 'Mz', 'extra']
reader = csv.reader(open('test.csv'))

for row in reader:
    for name, value in zip(fieldnames, row):
        # Note that the csv module only reads strings
        inner_output[name].append(float(value))        

output = {'session 1': inner_output}
```

Comment: If you used a `csv.DictReader` in the standard library version, the `zip(fieldnames, row)` wouldn't be necessary because each row would then be a dictionary.

Comment: @martineau all that buys you in this case is a `zip(fieldnames, row)` becomes `row.items()`. I didn't feel like the juice was worth the squeeze.